# UTF-8 does not work in Safari (inside iphone app)

Tags: ios, utf-8, ios-simulator

So I have almost no iphone programming experience, yet I have found some basic rss reader code and playing around with it.

The thing is, when I visit the link in my Chrome browser, it works fine in terms of character encoding, but when I visit it through the built-in browser in the iphone app code I have (in iphone simulator), the characters are not displayed properly.

Why it could be?

Edit:

So what I was trying to access over the web browser was a simple UTF-8 text file (I was too lazy to put into an HTML), and I could not see the non-English characters.

Comment: With mobile safari? With a web view? With some custom view you've created?  Your title is just plain false, UTF8 works fin in iPhone apps.

Comment: @rooftop: So there is this UTF-8 file (blahblah.txt) that works just fine on my desktop computer. Then I simply copy it to cvfsc.net/blahblah.txt and when I type in the URL in my iPad's Safari, it is not viewed correctly (=non-english chars not showing). Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: I wouldn't say that's "inside an iphone app", that to me implies that it's an app you have created, in reality you are using Apple's application, Safari.  As mentioned below, you need to tell the browser what the Charset of the file will be.  If you were writing your own app there are different ways to indicate the file is UTF8 depending on the situation, read file, http request etc.

Comment: Thank you, I updated question accordingly. Excuse my ignorance with terms, as I am just getting into the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must tell the client that the file is in UTF-8 format. If you are running apache, you can add this to your .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Or you can put the text into a HTML file and add a meta tag for the charset encoding:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: So it is not enough just putting a .txt saved in UTF-8 and hoping the browser will understand?

Comment: No, you must *always* associate an encoding with all texts. This is due to the mess caused in the 90s when everyone was using different encodings. Maybe in 20 years everything implicitly be UTF-8. But that is not the case yet.